# Using Access VBA to read JSON data

Tags: json, vba, api, rest, ms-access

I'm using the following VBA subroutine to read JSON data from a website:

```vb
Sub DistanceRetrieve()

      Dim url As String, attempts As Integer, strResponse  As String, strLatitude As String 

      Dim WinHttpReq As Object, Json As Object 

      url = "https://distances.dataloy.com/port/port?filter=portName(EQ)BERGEN"     

      attempts = 3     

      Set WinHttpReq = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0")     

      On Error GoTo TryAgain 

  TryAgain:   

      attempts = attempts - 1     

      Err.Clear     

      If attempts > 0 Then        

         With WinHttpReq           

             .Open "GET", url, False           

             .SetRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"           

             .Send          

             If .Status = 200 Then 

                 strResponse = .ResponseText              

                 Set Json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(strResponse)             

                 strLatitude = Json("latitude")           

             End If        

         End With     

      Else        

          MsgBox ("A4. No internet connection is available.")     

      End If

End Sub
```

Scripting Runtime and WinHTTP Services are referenced and Json Converter is imported. The subroutine, in its core, is found on many sites on the internet. After I run it,  strResponse contains just two characters; "[, while it should contain the following string:

```
[ {  "portName": "BERGEN",  "countryCode": "NO",  "countryName": "Norway",  "locationCode": "BGO",  "timezone": "Europe/Oslo",  "latitude": 60.392039,  "longitude": 5.306605,  "key": 104146}]
```

Also,  Json("latitude") statement gives "Invalid procedure call or argument" error message. Am I missing somthing?

Best regards.

Said

Comment: Something is missing (your credentials?), as that call returns: `{"message":"Forbidden"}`.

Comment: _Json("latitude") statement gives "Invalid procedure call or argument" error message._ The your code probably doesn't compile.

Comment: A SetRequestHeader statement with credentials was issued but not posted for confidentiality. The cod was compiled before run with no error messages.  The error message appeared only when run.

Comment: N.B. The long string shown in my post was read from the same site using the following code;

Comment: Dim oStream  As Object,                                                                                                                           
          Set oStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream"), 
          oStream.Open, 
          oStream.Type = 1, 
          oStream.Write WinHttpReq.ResponseBody, 
          oStream.SaveToFile 'filePath', 2, 
          oStream.Close

Comment: _The error message appeared only when run._ Then, I guess, `"Latitude"` is not the expected argument. Debug that.

Comment: After I replace "strLatitude = Json("latitude")" By:                                                                                  Dim Item As Object, For Each Item In Json, strLatitude = Item("latiyude"), Next, it succeeded

Comment: Dear Gustav, now I have another Json to read distance data, for which I applied the above mentioned "For...Next" loop, but again it failed. It gives "Object variable or With Block variable not set" error message for the statement "Distance = Item("distance"). I don't know how to pass the Json data to you, if it helps.

Comment: Post a new question with the new code and some sample data.